# Create Numpy 2D Array with data from triplets of (x,y,value)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, coordinates

I have a lot of data in database in `(x, y, value)` triplet form.
I would like to be able to create dynamically a 2D numpy array from this data by setting `value` at the coords `(x,y)` of the array.

For instance if I have :

```
(0,0,8)
(0,1,5)
(0,2,3)
(1,0,4)
(1,1,0)
(1,2,0)
(2,0,1)
(2,1,2)
(2,2,5)
```

The resulting array should be :

```
Array([[8,5,3],[4,0,0],[1,2,5]])
```

I'm new to numpy, is there any method in numpy to do so ? If not, what approach would you advice to do this ?

Comment: Also, explain how you got to the resulting array?

Comment: .... that's what i am asking ....

Comment: The question is ambiguous... iinformation is missing. n you example you are creating a 3x3 array from a 9x3 one... it seems you only want the last column.. but why kn a 3x3 array?

Comment: The first two values in triplets indicate coordinates in the 2d-array. If the input has 9 triplets the array will be 3x3, if the input has 16 triplets : 4x4, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending the answer from @MaxU, in case the *coordinates* are not ordered in a grid fashion (or in case some coordinates are missing), you can create your array as follows:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([(0,0,8),(0,1,5),(0,2,3),
              (1,0,4),(1,1,0),(1,2,0),
              (2,0,1),(2,1,2),(2,2,5)])
```

Here `a` represents your coordinates. It is an `(N, 3)` array, where `N` is the number of coordinates (it doesn't have to contain ALL the coordinates). The first column of `a` (`a[:, 0]`) contains the Y positions while the second columne (`a[:, 1]`) contains the X positions. Similarly, the last column (`a[:, 2]`) contains your *values*.

Then you can extract the maximum dimensions of your target array:

```
# Maximum Y and X coordinates
ymax = a[:, 0].max()
xmax = a[:, 1].max()

# Target array
target = np.zeros((ymax+1, xmax+1), a.dtype)
```

And finally, fill the array with data from your coordinates:

```
target[a[:, 0], a[:, 1]] = a[:, 2]
```

The line above sets values in `target` at `a[:, 0]` (all Y) and `a[:, 1]` (all X) locations to their corresponding `a[:, 2]` value (your *value*).

```
>>> target
array([[8, 5, 3],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 5]])
```

---

Additionally, if you have missing coordinates, and you want to replace those missing values by some number, you can initialize the array as:

```
default_value = -1
target = np.full((ymax+1, xmax+1), default_value, a.type)
```

This way, the coordinates not present in your list will be filled with `-1` in the target array/

Comment: Perfect, thanks ! I obvisouly missed this in numpy (`target[a[:, 0], a[:, 1]] = a[:, 2]`).

Comment: @ibi0tux Glad it helped! It is a vectorized assignment. It is essentially equivalent to `for (y, x, val) in a: target[y, x] = val`. But replacing the for loop with vectorized operations (much faster in numpy).

Comment: Well, indeed coordinates might be missing in this kind of triplets representation since it's very similar to a [sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) representation. See below for a very short and simple solution based on that.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using sparse matrices? (which is pretty much the format of your triplets.)

First split the triplets in rows, columns, and data using `numpy.hsplit()`. (Use `numpy.squeeze()` to convert the resulting 2d arrays to 1d arrays.)

```
>>> row, col, data = [np.squeeze(splt) for splt
...                   in np.hsplit(tripets, tripets.shape[-1])]
```

Use the sparse matrix in coordinate format, and convert it to an array.

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
>>> coo_matrix((data, (row, col))).toarray()
array([[8, 5, 3],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 5]])
```

Answer (score 2):

is that what you want?

```
In [37]: a = np.array([(0,0,8)
   ....:              ,(0,1,5)
   ....:              ,(0,2,3)
   ....:              ,(1,0,4)
   ....:              ,(1,1,0)
   ....:              ,(1,2,0)
   ....:              ,(2,0,1)
   ....:              ,(2,1,2)
   ....:              ,(2,2,5)])

In [38]:

In [38]: a
Out[38]:
array([[0, 0, 8],
       [0, 1, 5],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [1, 0, 4],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 5]])

In [39]:

In [39]: a[:, 2].reshape(3,len(a)//3)
Out[39]:
array([[8, 5, 3],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 5]])
```

or a bit more flexible (after your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409054/python-fill-numpy-2d-array-with-data-from-triplets/38409380#comment64227022_38409054)):

```
In [48]: a[:, 2].reshape([int(len(a) ** .5)] * 2)
Out[48]:
array([[8, 5, 3],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 5]])
```

Explanation:

this gives you the 3rd column (value):

```
In [42]: a[:, 2]
Out[42]: array([8, 5, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5])


In [49]: [int(len(a) ** .5)]
Out[49]: [3]

In [50]: [int(len(a) ** .5)] * 2
Out[50]: [3, 3]
```

Comment: This sounds great. Could you please just explain why you are doing `a[:, 2]` ?